# Check value when I have a list of elements separated by commas in a column?

Tags: csv, where, like

I am looking to return a value in a database.
Table named `TIPOLOGY` is structured like this:

```
Name   Owner   ID       Office  Type   LIST_OF_VALUES
Jones  Lasi      1       12345   TKT    AUD,PAX,CCF
Jones  Lasi      2       54321   TKT    AGT, FLT
Jones  Lasi      3       45689   TKT    IND,INV,CAS
```

I need to find the office and I have like information `NAME`, `OWNER`, `TYPE` and a `VALUE`.

So my basic query is:

```
SELECT Office FROM typology WHERE NAME=Jones AND OWNER=Lasi AND TYPE=TKT AND "AUD" in LIST.
```

Value AUD is only on one line, so it can return only one office.

However I don't know how to search for a value that is in a list inside the column `LIST_OF_VALUES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LIKE clause.

```
SELECT 
    Office
FROM 
    typology
WHERE 
    NAME='Jones' AND
    OWNER='Lasi' AND
    TYPE='TKT' AND
    LIST_OF_VALUES LIKE '%AUD%'
```